# Ver los detalles de un empleado

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos de empleados, con un formulario de busqueda, hace la busqueda del usuario dice el nombre, apellido, foto y el cargo.
Tengo abajo los nombres de los empleados y quiero que cuando le den clic abra una pagina con sus detalles (Nombre , Apellido, cargo y foto).

esta es mi consulta para ver los detalles

emp_detalles.php

```
<div id="content">

    details view.
<?php

$user = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbase = "employees_assign"; 
$table = "tbl_employees";

$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbase);
$sql = ("SELECT * from tbl_employees");
$emp= $connect->query($sql);


echo '<li id="names"><a href="index.php?id='.$emp['emp_id'].'">'.$emp['emp_fname'].' '.$emp['emp_lname'].' '.$emp['emp_lname'].' </a></li>';



?>

</div>
```

Pero me dice que

```
details view. 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp64\www\employees_done\views\emp_detail.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\employees_done\views\emp_detail.php on line 18
```

He intentado de todas las maneras, y no he podido que me de los detalles.

Agradezco la atención

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dice el error es que no se puede tratar un objeto del tipo mysqli_result como un array:

Entiendo que esto `$emp['emp_id']` debería ser reescrito así `$emp->emp_id`

Pero como te puede devolver más de un empleado:

```
<div id="content">

    details view.
    <?php

    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbase = "employees_assign";
    $table = "tbl_employees";

    $connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbase);
    $sql = ("SELECT * from tbl_employees");

    $empleados = $connect->query($sql);

    foreach ($empleados as $empleado) {
        echo '<li id="names"><a href="index.php?id=' . $empleado->emp_id . '">' . $empleado->emp_fname . ' ' . $empleado->emp_lname . ' ' . $empleado->emp_lname . ' </a></li>';
    }

    ?>

</div>
```